# Multiple custom product tabs not displaying in Magento2.3.1

Tags: magento2.3

```
   <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="whats_in_the_box.tab" template="Vendor_Module::product/view/whats_in_the_box.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Whats In the Box</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product_image_gallery.tab" template="Vendor_Module::product/view/product_image_gallery.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Gallery</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product_video.tab" template="Vendor_Module::product/view/product_video.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Video Gallery</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding sort_order field

```
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="whats_in_the_box.tab" template="Vendor_Digital::product/view/whats_in_the_box.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Whats In the Box</argument>
                <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">40</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product_image_gallery.tab" template="Vendor_Digital::product/view/product_image_gallery.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Gallery</argument>
                <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">50</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product_video.tab" template="Vendor_Digital::product/view/product_video.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Video Gallery</argument>
                <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">60</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```